# Grid header text not fitting when printing AdvancedDataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, air

I want to print an AdvancedDataGrid , I am using this code

```
public function doPrint():void {
            myPrintJob = new FlexPrintJob();
            myPrintDataGrid = new PrintAdvancedDataGrid();
            myPrintDataGrid.source=this.dataGrid;
            StageReference.instance.addElement(myPrintDataGrid);

            if (myPrintJob.start()) {   
                myPrintJob.addObject(myPrintDataGrid, FlexPrintJobScaleType.MATCH_WIDTH);
                myPrintJob.send();
                StageReference.instance.removeElement(myPrintDataGrid); 
            }
            else
            {
                StageReference.instance.removeElement(myPrintDataGrid);

            }
        }
```

The problem is the headers text is using a lot of padding or something similar so the text is not fitting

[image]

If someone can give me any hints, I do not know what to look for(maybe try to create my own header renderer?)

I found the cause, FlexPrintJob.addObject scales the grid and I think the headers need some more frames untill are updated, there are some strange things in the scaling, I noticed in debug that the width was set to 200 even if the page width is 600, no real solution for now then avoiding scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Flex label/text objects usually truncate the text if they think they don't have enough space.

I took a quick look at `AdvancedDataGridHeaderRenderer` and confirmed, that the renderer will set it's UITextField to truncate the text if the text is too wide **and** the grid's `variableRowHeight` property is false.

A snippet from AdvancedDataGridHeaderRenderer's commitProperties() method (line 462):

```
label.text = listData.label ? listData.label : " ";
label.multiline = grid.variableRowHeight;
// Get the headerWordWrap for a column, using the default wordWrap if none specified
if( _data is AdvancedDataGridColumn)
    label.wordWrap = grid.columnHeaderWordWrap(_data as AdvancedDataGridColumn);
```

The actual truncation happens in AdvancedDataGridHeaderRenderer's updateDisplayList() method (line 628).

Knowing this, you have some options:

- use the debugger to step through the code in commitProperties/updateDisplayList to see why the label objects in your headers **think** they need to be so small. In your screen shot, there appears to be plenty of space -- but for some reason the labels don't think so.
- override AdvancedDataGridHeaderRenderer's commitProperties/updateDisplayList methods to make it do exactly what you want
- set the grid/renderer's styles and properties to allow more width and/or multi-line text

To do the latter, you will want to do some combination of the following:

- use CSS to change font and other styles of AdvancedDataGridHeaderRenderer (default padding for this class is 2px)
- enable variableRowHeight for grid
- set the [wordWrap](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/AdvancedListBase.html#wordWrap) property of the grid to true (only works w/variable row height)
- or control word wrapping at the column level with the [headerWordWrap](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/advancedDataGridClasses/AdvancedDataGridColumn.html#headerWordWrap) property of `AdvancedDataGridColumn`

Comment: Thx for the response. I tried to debug but the update and invalidate functions are called a lot of times. I discovered that my grid is resized somehow I think scaled during the method addObject in FlexPrinJob and that scale makes my columns fotr a moment become 27px and that could cause the problem, the columns somehow get back to normal but no the headers.

Comment: Based on your comment and edit, perhaps you can buy a little more time by using Flex's `callLater()` method somewhere in the mix. Specifically: do `FlexPrintJob.addObject()` and then do `callLater(finishPrinting)` (where `finishPrinting` is a function that has code that finishes the task).

Comment: @SunilD.Thx again for your time, I also thinked about that but there is a loop surrounding that code  in FlexPrintJob.addObject and this trick will messup things more, I think the solution is not to scale the object but grab it's image scale it and print that or create a copy of the grid wait a few frame and print it  but modify the loop also to wait untill processing is done.